# Drag Listview Item on Top

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

How to drag array item when some code execute?

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain more about your problem?

Comment: if some code execute eg the ChatList if the new message comes then the Position of that ChatBox goes on top Of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Drag Listview Item on Top means 0th position:

```
getListView().setSelection(0);
```

For a smooth scroll:

```
getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Use this property. Hope this will help...